# .net google analytics v3.0 and oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

Here is what im trying to do , i got a webpage with signin page with cresedentials from our database , then once is logged in it should redirect you to main page where you should see the data in charts.

The problem is I used gdata v2.4  but every time i want make a request i have to set the cresedentials again, then v3.0 with oauth 2.0 it said we don't need to this anymore by access token.

I managed to make it work but  the problem is if the user been asked to login with gmail account and the email and password doesnt match the profile id of the request it gives the 403 error (forbidden access) this is the code . i tried to use service account no chance , any one knows whats the problem?

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    //string Scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.Analytics.ToString().ToLower();
    //string scopeUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/" + Scope;
    string Scope = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/";
    const string ServiceAccountId = "xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const string ServiceAccountUser = "xxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    string key = string.Empty;
    foreach (string keyname in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/"), "*.p12", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        key = keyname;
    }

    AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(
        GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, new X509Certificate2(key, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable))
    {
     Scope = Scope,   
        ServiceAccountId = ServiceAccountUser//,ServiceAccountUser = ServiceAccountUser
    };
      WebServerClient myWebServerClient = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    myWebServerClient.ClientIdentifier = this.ClientID;
    myWebServerClient.ClientSecret = this.ClientSecret;
    OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(myWebServerClient, GetAuthorization);

    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService(authenticator);
    string profileId = Session["_ProfileID"].ToString() ;
    string startDate = StartDate;
    string endDate = EndDate;
    string metrics = "ga:visits";
    DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics);
    request.Dimensions = "ga:date";
    request.StartIndex = 1;
    request.MaxResults = 500;
    GaData data = request.Fetch();
    return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

dont bother anymore , i got it right with offline access . Thanks for showing the SUPPORT